# Quarkus service stop serving requests after being stale for a certain amount of time

Tags: quarkus

Dears,

I am having a weird issue with Quarkus 1.13.x.Final. If my service stays up for a certain amount of time without being hit (idle) for 2+ hours, then a new request comes in no response is being returned. request get stuck!

I am using the below :
Java 11.
Quarkus 1.13.1.Final & 1.13.6.Final.
Docker & Docker Swarm.

Note that other endpoints like liveness & readiness checks works probably but not other endpoints.

Features Installed :
[cache, cdi, hibernate-validator, jaeger, mutiny, rest-client, rest-client-jackson, rest-client-mutiny, resteasy, resteasy-jackson, resteasy-mutiny, smallrye-context-propagation, smallrye-fault-tolerance, smallrye-health, smallrye-openapi, smallrye-opentracing, swagger-ui] and an example :

> @Path("/v1/profile") @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
> @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON) @Secured public class
> ProfileResource { @Path("get")
> @POST
> public Uni getUserProfile(){
> /*some code*/
> }  }

Comment: Which extensions does your application use? And what do your HTTP endpoints look like?

Comment: I've modified the question to answer your inquiries, thanks!

Comment: This sounds like a bug. I've never seen it happen, but I encourage you to open an issue

Comment: I tried to create a producer to it with no luck :(. I'll keep investigating about it.